# Custom control with Multiple Controls with same ID issue?

Tags: asp.net

I have a very simple custom control ive defined below:

```
public class TestCtrl : WebControl
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = new Button() { ID = "test", Text = "text"};
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}
```

However, when I wish to place multiple instances of them on the same page, I get...

> 'Multiple controls with the same ID 'test' were found.

...when `btn` is clicked.

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrl1 = new TestCtrl() { ID = "ctrl1" };
        plc.Controls.Add(ctrl1);
        var ctrl2 = new TestCtrl() { ID = "ctrl2" };
        plc.Controls.Add(ctrl2);
    }
```

Is there a clean way to stop this from happening? Ive tried setting ClientIDMode to 'Auto' without any success, as the `name` property of the rendered markup is `"test"` on both buttons.

EDIT: Solved by adding 'INamingContainer' to the control 
`public class TestCtrl : WebControl, INamingContainer{...}`

Comment: Try creating a property on your TestCtrl class and setting the value

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Solved by adding 'INamingContainer' to the control public class TestCtrl : WebControl, INamingContainer{...}

Answer (score 0):

Because you have specified the ID of your btn in the OnInit Method equal to "test" therefore when you add the control to the page It set the ID = test for the control. I think there is no need to set the ID property in the OnInit() Method. Add the following code to your render method

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = new Button() { Text = "text"}; // No need to add ID property
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: No, bad idea. If the control is recreated without an id, it will adopt a new id/name attribute, thus not trigger any attached evens the following postback.

Comment: @maxp you are creating a custom server control ?

Comment: Yes, as per the sample above.

Comment: @maxp but you have not override the Render method ?

Comment: @maxp For custom server control it is not necessary to give values to the properties at design time. When we use the control then we assign value to properties. When you place this control on a page a new ID automatically assings to the control, there is no chance of repatings ID's .

Comment: @maxp sorry it is Custom Server control. and design time means when you are creating your control.

Comment: @maxp see my updated ans I have placed an example of custom server control.

Comment: Solved myself, please see my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your going about it the wrong way.

```
 public class TestCtrl : WebControl, INamingContainer {

     private button btn;

     [Bindable(true), Category("Content"), DefaultValue(""), Description("Gets or Sets the Fields that are to be added to the ListItems")]
     public string TextField {
        get { EnsureChildControls(); return btn.Text; } 
        set { EnsureChildControls(); btn.Text = value; }
     }

     [Bindable(true), Category("Content"), DefaultValue(""), Description("Gets or Sets another field of your choice")]
     public string SomeStringField{
        get { return ViewState["_someStringField"] != null ? ViewState["_someStringField"].ToString() : String.Empty ;  }
        set { ViewState["_someStringField"] = value; }
     }

     protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
         base.OnInit(e);
     }

     protected override void CreateChildControls() {
         btn = new button();
         btn.id = "btn";

         this.Controls.Add(btn);
     }

     protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
         writer.Write(<b>SomeStringField + ":</b>");
         btn.RenderControl(writer);
     }

 }
```

After adding it to your page

This will display a label then the button next to it.  You want to but the id in the CreateChildControls so that it will be assigned a unique ID.  The EnsureChildControls will make sure that the properties are loaded correctly.  You can call this method from pretty much anywhere in the control but I would do it after OnInit.  If not then the Id's will be confused.  Sometimes they will work and others they do not.  Javascript of Jquery will give you a head ache as well.

I would refer to Microsofts examples.  They have many of them and very helpfull.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479016.aspx